# SPRESENSEにArduino用のカメラモジュールを使用した際のライブラリについて

Tags: spresense

お世話になります。
基本的な質問で恐縮ですが、ご存じの方がおりましたらご教示願います。

現在、SPRESENSEにArduino用のカメラモジュールを用いて画像解析をしようと検討しております。
この構成にてSPRESENSE SDKにありますCamera ライブラリを利用することは可能なのでしょうか？

この場合はどのライブラリを使用すべきか教えていただけますと幸いです。
もし、その他アドバイス等がありましたらコメントのほどよろしくお願いた際ます。

Answer (score 0):

OV7670のようなArduinoで使われているカメラを使いたいということでしょうか？もしそうだとしたら、SDKのカメラライブラリそのままでは使えないと思います。

Spresense Arduino Library のCameraライブラリのソースを見るとわかりますが、Spresenseのカメラ機能は、v4l2経由でコントロールするようになっていますので、お使いのカメラのnuttx用のドライバを作る必要があると思います。

もし、お使いのカメラにArduinoライブラリがあるなら、そちらを検討したほうが近道かもしれません。あまりアドバイスになっていませんが、ご参考になれば幸いです。